# when maximizing Panel,how to make the map within Panel growing synchronizely?

Tags: apache-flex, arcgis

I have a map in a panel.When maximizing the panel,the map remain the smaller size.How to make the map growing synchronizely with the Panel?

When maximizing the Panel,I added Resize Effects.How to apply Resize effects on the Map when the extent of the map changing?

It seems to me that I should dispatch extentChange event when maximizing the panel.

Could anyone give me some hint?

Much Thanks!

(I'm very young in flex learning)

Best,Shuo

Answer (score 0):

If your inner map/panel has percent widths/heights, it should resize with it automatically.  Make sure it looks like this:

```
<mx:Panel id="outer" width="100%" height="100%">
    <!-- percent sizes on map (panel is just for example) -->
    <mx:Panel id="inner" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</mx:Panel>
```

... not this (explicit):

```
<mx:Panel id="inner" width="400" height="500"/>
```

... or this (measured):

```
<mx:Panel id="inner"/>
```

Let me know if that works.

Best,
Lance